# Best practice to sync just one Evernote notebook through Cloud API

Tags: api, evernote

I'm working on an web appliaction that will sync the content of **only one Evernote notebook** in the user's account. I have read the [Evernote Synchronization via EDAM](http://dev.evernote.com/media/pdf/edam-sync.pdf) from Evernote. Still would like to know what  the best practice would be.

I'm not going to sync every notebook in the user's account. One way is by using `NoteStore.getSyncChunk` or `NoteStore.getFilteredSyncChunk`. While the other is using  `NoteStore.findNotesMetadata` with a `NoteFilter.word` set with `updated:[datetime]` search term ([Search Grammar - Search Terms](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/search_grammar.php#Search_Terms)) .

Here's my questions:

What would the best practice when I sync the content at the first time? Should I use "sync chunk" or just "find notes".

For further syncs, is it okay to sync through "find notes" and filter by updated time?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging in more on the Evernote documentation, I found my answers. Refer to the [Watching for Changes](http://dev.evernote.com/documentation/cloud/chapters/polling_notification.php) at Evernote website, I should use `NoteStore.findNoteMetadata` for my initial sync and register for a webhook which will let Evernote notify me whenever an change is made.

Using Sync Chunk for initial sync is does not help me sync just one Evernote notebook after all.